# accessing custom objects in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, onclicklistener

I'm currently building an app that has a request being sent into the web, the result then gets parsed and put into an ArrayList of objects.

this list then, populates a ListView.
I want to create an `onClickListener` that will allow me to know which object was clicked, but I can't find the correct way to implement this.

either assign the onClick to the ListView in the original activity, or, assign the listener within the `getView` function in the custom adapter.

it seems to me like assigning the listeners in the `getView` has too much overhead.

how does it work? what is better?

**code for main activity:**

```
public class NoPicList extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    NoPicAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.no_pic_list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.noPicListView);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String request = b.getString("REQUEST");
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.setMessage("Lodaing Data");
        mDialog.show();

        new GetNewsAndCalendar().execute(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPause();
    }

    class GetNewsAndCalendar extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Message>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Message> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            DOMFeedParser parser = new DOMFeedParser(url);
            return parser.parse();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Message> result) {
            adapter = new NoPicAdapter(NoPicList.this, result);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            //FIRST OPTION TO INSERT onClickListener
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }    //end of GetNewsAndCalendar
}
```

**code for list adapter:**

```
public class NoPicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Message> data;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public NoPicAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Message> result) {
        mActivity = a;
        data = result;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.no_pic_list_item,
                null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.noPicTitle);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.noPicSubtitle);

        title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        subtitle.setText(data.get(position).getDate());
    // SECOND PLACE TO INSERT THE onClickListener
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my concern, assign the **onClick to the ListView in the original activity** is good idea, rather then assigning it to in `getView()` of your custom adapter. Because in `getView()` of your adapter it always create a **new View.onClick()'s object**..

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
  {
   adapter.get(position);  
   // Get data from your adapter,   the above code of line give the custom adapter's object of   current position of selected list item     
  }   
 });
```

Comment: `setOnItemSelectedListener`? for what?

Comment: @PareshMayani - Oh sorry, My mistake it was onItemClickListener.. Thanks for it.

Comment: I think the `onClickListener` can not get a `onItemSelectedListener`. therefor it has to be an `onItemSelectedListener`

Comment: @MoeJo - Yes, you are right, Its just typing mistake, I correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with **user370305**'s answer.

You just need to implement `OnItemClickListener` in your Activity class, after creating you will get onItemClick method, inside that you will get **position** of the clicked object.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyObject clickedObject = (MyObject) adapter.getItem(position);
        // MyObject is user-defined class

    }
```

Comment: **adapter.getItem(position);** will return him position variable. look at his adapter code.. and it will throw class cast exception..

Comment: @sandy yes it is, i just showed him a way to implement OnItemClick event, for the rest part he should try by their hand.

Comment: @sandy, the `getItem(position)` is gonna be implemented right now, I haven't implemented it yet...