# Getting custom object on click from ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm displaying a ListView that I filled with a custom ListAdapter, called LazyAdapter, which code comes from here : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/. The LazyAdapter uses my custom objects "EventData". I managed to display my List as I wanted, but now I'd like to get the clicked object. I found some help on other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275911/accessing-custom-objects-in-a-listview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508979/android-listview-get-selected-item), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834750/how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-listview)), and wrote that code:

```
private OnItemClickListener mEventClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        EventData selectedEvent = (EventData) eventsListView.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

};
```

However, I get a cast error at execution.

```
05-14 17:10:46.718: E/AndroidRuntime(3863): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
```

I also tried this similar solution:

```
EventData selectedEvent = (EventData) av.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

I got the same cast error. I don't know how I can get my Object EventData in an other way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post your Adapter code

Comment: Agreed, it seems like your Adapter's `getItem()` is returning an unexpected value.  (Ultimately, ListView's `getItemAtPosition()` is just calling through to your Adapter's `getItem()` function.

Comment: How do you fill/create your LazyAdapter? It seams that the ArrayList you gives to your adapter is an array of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom list adapter you return an integer in `getItem();` so you will receive `ClassCastException`

`mEventData` is list which is supplied to CustomListView

```
ArrayList<EventData> mEventData;

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mEventData.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that in my LazyAdapter class. Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

In the adapter class, in the method `getItem(int position)` you should return the `EventData` object for that position (not the position).

You may have returning `Position` value in `getItem` instead of  `EventData`.

Answer (score 0):

In my code fetching the object I do

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> appList, View arg1,
                int element, long arg3) {
            // Get AppData for demo clicked
            AppData item = demoList.get(element);
```

where demoList is the underlying data structure (ArrayList < AppData>) bound to the adapter